# Pull/push student assignment files from computer lab computers (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

I have a computer lab with about 35 PC's all running Windows 7.

The students do their work and save it on the D-drive in a particular folder such as a folder with the same name as the computer's name (e.g.  LABPC001).

I'd like a centralized way to pull all these folders in to the teacher's computer in the lab to check the assignments.  It would be best if this didn't involve using an external website (e.g. Dropbox).

I would also like to be able to distribute (send) files to the students in these same folders.

I've seen software applications that do this but they cost about US$1000 which is far beyond our means.

Suggestions for free, or almost free, best ways to set this up?

Comment: I'd recommend rsync from teacher's machine, combined with easy batch scripting. In fact you can use robocopy or xcopy as well, just need a list of student pcs ips/names and credentials

Answer (score 0):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is a file-synchronization tool for Unix and Windows. It allows two replicas of a collection of files and directories to be stored on different hosts (or different disks on the same host), modified separately, and then brought up to date by propagating the changes in each replica to the other.

Unison shares a number of features with tools such as configuration management packages (CVS, PRCS, Subversion, BitKeeper, etc.), distributed filesystems (Coda, etc.), uni-directional mirroring utilities (rsync, etc.), and other synchronizers (Intellisync, Reconcile, etc). However, there are several points where it differs:

Unison runs on both Windows and many flavors of Unix (Solaris, Linux, OS X, etc.) systems. Moreover, Unison works across platforms, allowing you to synchronize a Windows laptop with a Unix server, for example.

Unlike simple mirroring or backup utilities, Unison can deal with updates to both replicas of a distributed directory structure. Updates that do not conflict are propagated automatically. Conflicting updates are detected and displayed.
Unlike a distributed filesystem, Unison is a user-level program: there is no need to modify the kernel or to have superuser privileges on either host.

Unison works between any pair of machines connected to the internet, communicating over either a direct socket link or tunneling over an encrypted ssh connection. It is careful with network bandwidth, and runs well over slow links such as PPP connections. Transfers of small updates to large files are optimized using a compression protocol similar to rsync.

Unison is resilient to failure. It is careful to leave the replicas and its own private structures in a sensible state at all times, even in case of abnormal termination or communication failures.

Unison has a clear and precise specification.
Unison is free; full source code is available under the GNU Public License.

Comment: This sounds good... the relationship in the computer lab is one-to-many (one teacher PC to many student PCs).  Will Unison be able to do that?  The description above says "any pair of machines", so I am not sure about one-to-many?

Comment: It should because it is client-server, so it can pair any folder from a client with server's folder, is not it what you need? More in the [manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about configuring standard windows share out the D: drive on each of the student machines and easily pull it down to the teacher machine.